# CakePHP Auth->loginRedirect not working

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakePHP 2.2.

In my before filter of my App Controller I have the following:

```
    // Admin
    if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '12') {
            $this->Auth->allow('admin_index'); 
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => TRUE);
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);

            $this->set("group", "admin");

    // Staff
    } elseif($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '13') {
            $this->Auth->allow('admin_index'); 
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => TRUE);
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);

            $this->set("group", "staff");

    // Users
    } else {

            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false);
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);

            $this->set("group", "user");
        }
```

The first and second if's work fine and redirect the users to the appropriate pages on login, however the third redirect doesn't work at all, it just leaves you on the login pages, but it does display the flash_success message from the login function???

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

* Added information requrested from Tim ***

User controller before filter and login function:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('logout');
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
    $this->Auth->allow('forgetpwd');
    $this->Auth->allow('reset');
    $this->Auth->allow('initDB');
    $this->Auth->allow('register');
    //$this->Auth->allow('admin_importOldUsers');
    //$this->Auth->allow('*');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $userStatusCheck = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.username'=>$this->request->data['User']['username'])));

        // If user is not deleted
        if ($userStatusCheck['User']['live'] == 1) {

            // Users status.
            /* 1 = Disabled, 2 = Enabled, 3 = Waiting for Auth, 4 = refer to Darren */
            $us = $userStatusCheck['User']['user_status_id'];

            // If account is disabled
            if ($us == 1) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been disabled, please conntact our support team.', 'flash_failure');
            } 

            // If account is waiting for authorisation
            else if ($us == 3) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your account is waiting to be authorised', 'flash_failure');
            }

            // If accoutn is referred to Darren
            else if ($us == 4) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your account is waiting to be authorised', 'flash_failure');
            } 

            // Account is enabled, proceed to login
            else if ($us == 2) {

                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!', 'flash_success');
                        //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

                        if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '12' OR $this->Auth->user('group_id') == '13'){
                            $this->redirect('/admin/');
                        } else {
                            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                        }
                    }            
                }
                else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.', 'flash_failure');
                }
            }

        } else {

            $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been disabled, please conntact our support team.', 'flash_failure');

        }

    }
```

Comment: Just a stretch but you don't have an `isAuthorized()` override on the pages controller denying users? How is the redirect called? Could you be missing a call like `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect())` on the login function?

Comment: isn't `'admin' => false` by default? do you need all those extra params in there?

Comment: Let's see your login function and your beforeFilter in the users controller

Comment: @TimJoyce Added info as requested. I forgot I added a redirected for the working groups, so this would mean $this->auth-redirect() is not working - but why? Thanks again

Comment: Isn't there any logical flaw in your AppController code ? In your two first conditions, what's the aim of setting a login action and a login redirect when the user is already authenticated ? Or is the user already authenticated by the Auth component at this step, but not redirected yet ?

Comment: Just thinking, I'm checking in the app controllers before filter for the auth->user('group_id'), will this even exist at his point? All I'm trying to do is redirect to the admin page or the client page depending on the user group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I've still not got the AppController beforefilter auth redirect code working for users group, I've managed to fudge it in the login() funciton of the usersController using this code:

```
if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '12' OR $this->Auth->user('group_id') == '13'){
$this->redirect('/admin/');
} else {    
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false)); #this does not work...
    //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); # Does not work
}
```

But the key to get that else working was this line

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false));
```

To the AppController beforeFeature making it:

```
if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '14') {
        $this->Auth->allow(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false));
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);

        $this->set("group", "user");
    }
```

This feels like a total fudge but after spending days reading SO and various other sites and the cake docs I can see no other way of making the auth componant redirect to different pages on login depending on the users group.

If anyone finds a better way to do this I'd LOVE to know!